# Laravel 4.2 event is fired twice

Tags: php, laravel, events, redis

2 and I'm firing events so that I can run an app in real time. However when I fire the event it is being fired twice. e.g.

```
    $ret = json_encode(['message'=>'efr']);
    \Event::fire('data.doRefresh',[$ret]);
```

I then have this function which is setup to listen;

```
 public function doRefresh($data)
    {

        $redis = \Redis::connection();
        $redis->publish('data.refresh', $data);
        \Log::info('Event Handler Fired - Refreshing Data');

    }
```

And when i check my logs I can see it being logged twice;

```
[2016-02-27 17:47:20] dev.INFO: Event Handler Fired - Refreshing Data [] []
[2016-02-27 17:47:20] dev.INFO: Event Handler Fired - Refreshing Data [] []
```

Any ideas why this is occurring and how i can get it to fire only the once?

Comment: I realize this is old but has there been any answer to this?

Comment: @enchance no there is no answer to this. Do you have any suggestions?